# Set the color of the text depending on the color of the background

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is colored dynamically and inside that div there is a text. I would like the color of the text will be white or black depending of the darkness of the color of the div.

So if for example the color of the div is dark brown I would like the color of the text be white. If the color of the div is yellow, I would like the color of the text be black.

How to do that with HTML/CSS/PHP?

Javier

Comment: How are you setting the background colour? You should set the foreground colour at the same time.

Comment: [How to Calculate a Complementary Colour](http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php)

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the colour of the Div? An extension of what Doug said...

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("yourDynamicDiv");
myDiv.style.color = "black";
```

if you set the colour manually add that at the same time.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

This function will take any hexcolor and return either white or black depending on what has more contrast.

```
function TextContrast($hexcolor){

$hexcolor = str_replace("#","","$hexcolor");

if(!$hexcolor){
$hexcolor = "FFFFFF";
}

    $r = hexdec(substr($hexcolor,0,2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($hexcolor,2,2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hexcolor,4,2));
    $yiq = (($r*299)+($g*587)+($b*114))/1000;
    if($yiq >= 128){
        $text_color = "#000000";
        }
        else{
        $text_color = "#FFFFFF";
        }

} // end text contrast function
```

For your style sheet, you can change the .css extension to .php and add

```
.custom_div {background: #FF00FF;}
<?php TextContrast("FF00FF"); ?>
.custom_div {color: <?php echo $text_color; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, will the colors be pre-determined, or the user will generate it? If you're going with the predetermined colors, you can set classes for the parent and the child can now where it is via css and adjust accordingly. Below is an example on how.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"> Enter Content Here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.black-bg {
   background:#000000;
}

.black-bg div {
   color:#FFFFFF;
}

.white-bg {
   background:#FFFFFF;
}

.white-bg div {
   color:#000000;
}
```

Everytime you change the class on the parent, it will force the browser to re-render the area, hence enabling dynamic styling.

I don't know php, but you can do it in JS like this:

**JS** (jquery)

```
   if ( x === condition-1 ) {
      $(".parent").addClass(".black-bg");
   } else if ( x === condition-2 ) {
      $(".parent").addClass(".white-bg"); 
   }
```